# Debian Jessie (8.x) crashed while compiling python package

Tags: debian, boot, crash

Hopefully this board can help with my unique situation.

**Back ground information:**
My computer runs debian Jessie with encrypted LVM. I was installing a few python packages onto it through the 'sudo pip install' command, and while 'pandas' was compiling, the terminal froze and the computer went to the screen with the blinking underscore in the top left corner (the underscore was not flashing, just showing).

While this was happening, I had a few firefox windows open and I was running a program in the JVM

To shutdown my computer, I held the power button to force it to shutdown.

The computer booted to grub rescue saying 'error: disk '(,gpt2)' cannot be found', or something similar. I can get the exact phrase and drives that are displaying if it's relevant.

**What I have tried so far:** I went through the process of creating a bootable xubuntu usb stick, and I installed boot-repair to try and see if that program would solve the issue. The "recommended repair" button did not show up probably because of the LVM. Here is the boot-summary: https://pastebin.com/eTkgyUL9 (I apologize if external links are frowned upon)

I'm trying to fix /dev/sda so it boots again, and it seems that it has a corrupted partition table. I don't have any particular important information on the computer, and everything has already been backed up. I can answer detailed questions about my computer system, so don't hesitate to ask. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** It seems like I can restore the partition table on the drive by using the backup. Would someone with more experience with grub, grub-rescue, fdisk, etc. please comment on this? How would I go about this?

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F87898F5-F345-46E5-B200-FE992BA23671

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624    1550335     499712  244M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  1550336 3907028991 3905478656  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue! I'm not sure how the GPT partition table got corrupted, but I was able to fix it using `sudo gdisk`

1. I first saw that the  primary GPT table is corrupt but the backup seemed to be fine. From a bootable Linux usb drive...

   `xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
   The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
   Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
   Disklabel type: gpt
   Disk identifier: F87898F5-F345-46E5-B200-FE992BA23671`

   Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
   /dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
   /dev/sda2  1050624    1550335     499712  244M Linux filesystem
   /dev/sda3  1550336 3907028991 3905478656  1.8T Linux filesystem
2. `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`

   GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

   Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
   backup header from main header.

   Partition table scan:
     MBR: protective
     BSD: not present
     APM: not present
     GPT: damaged

   ---

   Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
   verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.

   ---

   Command (? for help):
3. You can type `?` for command help. In sequence I used `p`, then `w`, then the program asks for confirmation with `Y/N`.

   Command (? for help): w

   Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
   PARTITIONS!!

   Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
   OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sda.
   Warning: The kernel is still using the old partition table.
   The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you
   run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
   The operation has completed successfully.
4. Run `sudo partprobe` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdxX` to make sure everything turned out okay.